# Get stream of new Facebook likes for your application

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get response from Graph API (or FQL) that will list new likes for application and objects tied to it? Meaning - I created application, posted Like buttons all over the site - can I now get feed that will tell me what are the last 10 likes my pages received?

Related - can I somehow get list of last 10 likes of my Fan Page (something like New Likes box in Admin section)?

Comment: Did you ever work this one out?

Comment: Got caught up with bunch of other obligations so I still need to look into suggestions guys below provided. They are not exactly what I was looking for - but they seem like OK alternatives - Facebook is obviously to blame as they are probably intentionally making it hard to take your data out of their platform - they want to keep it from themselves.

Comment: Any updates on your progress or have you resolved this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question #1:**

You can use **[Real-time Updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/)**

> Here are the steps to set up a subscription:
>
> 1. Set up an endpoint URL that receives both HTTP GET (for subscription verification) and > POST (for actual change data) requests from Facebook.
> 2. Make a POST to the graph API url https://graph.facebook.com//subscriptions to >   subscribe, and be ready to handle the verification request.

What you get:

> User connections to which you can subscribe: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins.

What you don't get (yet):

> home, tagged, posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox, updates, accounts.

**Question #2:**

Sure you can !
go to your [Page Notifications](https://www.facebook.com/notifications?id=XXXXXX) (replace XXXX with your page ID)
you will find there an RSS link which you can use without even making a Graph API call

> You will receive notifications when visitors interact with your page.
>   For example, if a visitor likes your page or a fan writes on your
>   wall, you will receive a notification.

Answer (score 7):

There is no public Facebook API that will allow you to receive a stream of the most recent likes for a collection of objects.

Furthermore, it doesn't appear to be possible to obtain a stream of likes ordered specifically by time, however it *is* possible to receive a list of user IDs who liked an object using the `like` FQL table.

> like: An FQL table that returns the IDs of users who like a given object (video, note, link, photo, or album).

For example, to retrieve a list of all the user ids who liked the 'Facebook' page, you would use the FQL query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="122706168308"
```

Which would return a list similar to this:

```xml
<fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
<like>
<user_id>100003494051884</user_id>
</like>
<like>
<user_id>100003621882407</user_id>
</like>
<like>
<user_id>100003664580513</user_id>
</like>
<like>
<user_id>100002342537723</user_id>
</like>
<like>
<user_id>100001712929866</user_id>
</like>
<like>
<user_id>100003278394112</user_id>
</like>
</fql_query_response>
```

The order of the user IDs isn't clear - it may be in no specific order, or it may be ordered by time. I'd recommend that you have a bit of a fiddle with FQL and likes to see if it is in any particular order. You should also take a look at the other examples documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/).

---

As mentioned by [Roni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063011/1166205), it is possible to use the notifications RSS feed of your page to retrieve an RSS 2.0/XML feed of ***all*** notifications, sorted by time.

It may be possible to parse that XML to find the users who most recently liked your page, but the feed can get messy: it basically contains the HTML for each notification on the notifications page.